# Laravel Eloquent - Query builder cant find column with having function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a pivot table 'game_genre'(with game_id and genre_id). The game and genre model has a `belongsToMany` relationship similar to example below.

I have been attempting to gather the games which contain both genre_id of 60 and 55 together. I have been getting the correct result using the following SQL query, but when using the following query builder I end up getting a column not found error when using the `having()` function.

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'genre_id' in 'having clause'`

Im not sure how else to structure the query builder?

MODEL:

```
class Game extends Model
{    
    public function genres()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre');
    }
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM game_genre
WHERE genre_id = 55 OR genre_id = 60
GROUP BY game_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genre_id) = 2;
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$game = Game::whereHas('genres', function ($query)
{
    $query->where('genre_id', '55')
        ->orWhere('genre_id', '60')
        ->groupBy('game_id')
        ->having('genre_id','=', 2);
})->get();
```

Comment: ->having('genre_id','=', 2); should be ->having('genre_id','=', 2)

Comment: or try ->havingRaw('genre_id = 2')

Comment: If you want to get the game of gener_jd 60 & 55; You can put a relationship function (gener) in Game model in which put a statement return $this->belongsToMany(Gener::class, 'game_gener'); And then try to get the result from this query $games = Game::gener()->where('gener_id',55)->orWhere('gener_id',60)->get(); Be sure you are putting a relationship function as static otherwise you have to call relationship function on object;

Comment: @DevinGray - I tried discluding the `;` from the `having()` function, but it creates a syntax error. The `havingRaw()` function just creates same error result as with the standard one.

Comment: @AmitKumar - Ok I tried your method, but im not sure how to get it working statically and calling from object just outputs `undefined method`...can you elloborate, or provide example plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the aggregate function (in this case `COUNT`) in your `HAVING` condition:

```
$query->where('genre_id', '55')
    ->orWhere('genre_id', '60')
    ->groupBy('game_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT genre_id) = 2');
```

Instead of adding several `where()` and `orWhere()` to your query, you could also use `whereIn()` which takes an array:

```
$myArray = [55,60];
$query->whereIn('genre_id', $myArray)
    ->groupBy('game_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT genre_id) = 2');
```

Comment: This seems slightly neater than repeating a `whereHas()` like Amits method, Im leaning towards using this one. Im wondering if you know why the raw sql works and using the standard `having()` function does not detect the column?

Comment: @Orbitall my guess is that you don't have `genre_id` in your `SELECT` list. `HAVING` can only use columns that are either in the `SELECT` list, in the `GROUP BY` clause or used in an aggregate function.

Comment: @Orbitall oh and the standard `having()` doesn't work in this case because it only works with a column name as first argument. This means you can't use `COUNT` and that's why you need to use `havingRaw()`.

Comment: Thanks, good explainations...Although Im finding Amits method more usefull in a foreach loop eg.($ids = [55,60]). When I added yours to a foreach, the response came back with games that had one of the ids not both. Can you show me how yours could be modified to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the `Games` which contain both `genre_id` of `60` and `55`:

```
$games = Game::whereHas('genres', function ($query) {
                $query->where('genre_id', '55');
            })
            ->whereHas('genres', function ($query) {
                $query->where('genre_id', '60');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: This one looks like it could work much better in a loop than the `havingRaw()` method.